# Possible causes of the published js file broken

Tags: javascript, c#, publish

After I published the application to file system by Visual Studio 2015.
Some js files become unopenable or the size is very large (original 20kb then become 50mb).

I would like to ask what is the possible reason for that?
Those js files hasn't been edited in the development process.

I tried to google but couldn't find the related topics.
May I know what keywords should I use next time?

Comment: Any plugin you install? the one that can modify js would be some sort of obfuscation tool.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Is JavaScript Snippet Pack?

Comment: I don't think that extension would do something like that, its unlikely to be visual studio issue. Can you give more hints like what content is in your 50mb file? How do you deploy your application? what is inside your project post Build Events?